# Задача по sql: вывести самые популярные события в самый популярный год

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть табличка с полями `id` - PK AI, `event` - название события, `year` - год, в котором событие произошло:

```
events:
id | event | year
1  |   X   | 2000
2  |   X   | 2000
3  |   Y   | 2000
4  |   Z   | 2001
6  |   T   | 2002
```

**1)** Нужно вывести самые популярные события в самый популярный год. Т.е. в данном случае самый популярный год 2000, т.к. в нём произошло сразу 3 события. А самое популярное событие в 2000 году - X.

Результат должен быть в виде: **событие, кол-во, год**.

```
event | cnt | year
 X    |  2  | 2000
```

**2)** Если самых популярных событий несколько, то нужно вывести все самые популярные события в самый популярный год. Например для:

```
id | event | year
1  |   X   | 2000
3  |   Y   | 2000
4  |   Z   | 2001
6  |   T   | 2002
```

sql-запрос должен вернуть 2 ряда:

```
event | cnt | year
 X    |  1  | 2000
 Y    |  1  | 2000
```

**3)** Написать sql-запрос, который бы выводил самые популярные события в самые популярные годы. Т.е. может быть несколько самых популярных лет. Например:

```
id | event | year
1  |   X   | 2000
3  |   Y   | 2000
4  |   Z   | 2001
6  |   T   | 2001
7  |   W   | 2005
```

Результат должен быть:

```
event | cnt | year
 X    |  1  | 2000
 Y    |  1  | 2000
 Z    |  1  | 2001
 T    |  1  | 2001
```

1) Мой вариант - первый запрос можно написать как (работает верно не на всех данных):

```
select event, count(*) cnt, year from events group by year, event order by cnt desc limit 1;
```

- Как исправить запрос для варианта 1?
- Как правильно написать sql-запрос, чтобы он работал для варианта 2 и 3?

Comment: У вас запрос для варианта 1 кстати не верный. Если в 2000 году будет скажем еще пара событий с совершенно другими буквами, а за 2002 будет еще 2 события T, то ваш запрос вернет событие T 2002 т.к. их будет 3. А за самый популярный 2000 год одинаковых событий (X) только 2

Comment: @Mike действительно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**

```
select event, year, count(1) cnt
  from events
 where year=(select year from events group by year order by count(1) desc limit 1)
 group by event, year
 order by cnt desc
 limit 1
```

**2.**

```
select event, year, count(1) cnt
  from events
 group by event, year
 having (year,count(1))=
  (
   select year, count(1) from events
    where year =(select year from events group by year order by count(1) desc limit 1)
    group by event, year
    order by count(1) desc limit 1
  )
```

**3.**

```
select event, year, count(1) cnt
  from events
 group by event, year
having (year,count(1)) in
  (
   select year, max(cnt) m from (
       select year, event,count(1) cnt
         from events
        group by year, event
      ) A
    group by year
   having sum(cnt)=(
      select count(1) cnt from events
       group by year order by count(1) desc limit 1
     )
   )
```

И любители поломать голову с переменными MySQL могут воспользоватся таким вариантом (возможно более быстрый, в случае когда много однотипных событий):

```
select year,event,cnt
  from
   (
    select *,@yc:=cnt+if(year=@y,@yc,0) yc,
             @mcnt:=if(year!=@y,cnt,@mcnt) mcnt,
             @yl:=if(@yc>@myc,year,if(@yc=@myc,concat(@yl,',',year),@yl)),
             @myc:=if(@myc<@yc,@yc,@myc),
             @y:=year
      from (
        select year, event,count(1) cnt
          from events
         group by year, event
      ) A,(select @yc:=0,@y:=0,@mcnt:=0,@yl:='',@myc:=0) B
     order by year,cnt desc
   ) A
 where find_in_set(year,@yl)>0 and cnt=mcnt
```

Comment: если я не туплю, то последний вариант и, соответсвенно, запрос должен всегда и работать

Comment: Возможно. Смотря что считать "самым популярным годом" если таких годов несколько. Я предпочитаю считать, что нужен один любой, тогда варианты 1 и 2 понадобятся. Ну и по ним можно посмотреть как движется мысль при построении варианта 3 :)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Все варианты работают как надо! А не могли бы вы еще пояснить эту запись: `having (year,count(1)) in` -- как оно работает?

Comment: @jekaby Думаю обычный `A in(select B)` вы знаете, который выбирает все A которые дает ему подзапрос. `(A,B) in(select C,D)` дает все записи где равны пары колонок, т.е. записи у которых `A=C and B=D`. Подзапрос в нашем случае выбирает year,max(cnt), т.е. пары ГОД--максимальное_кол-во_одинаковых_событий А having уже оставляет от верхней группировки записи у которых указанные года И кол-во событий равно перечисленным подзапросом

Comment: Я так и подумал, просто еще ни разу не применял такую технику `having (A, B)`.. Ожидал, что более простыми запросами получится. ок, спасибо!